# How do I resolve these conflicting Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have an entry in my routes.rb that looks like this:

```
resources :baskets, :shallow => true, :only => :show
  resource :owned, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end

get '/baskets/owned', :to => 'owners#index'
```

This creates routes that look like:

```
basket        GET    /baskets/:id(.:format)
baskets_owned GET    /baskets/owned(.:format)
# ...
```

But now, when I call /baskets/owned, I get this:

```
Started GET "/baskets/owned" for 10.0.1.2 at 2011-06-09 10:31:33 -0400
  Processing by BasketsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"owned"}
```

What's the most idiomatic way to resolve this routing conflict?

Answer (score 8):

Rails matches routes starting from the first-defined and proceeding down until it finds a match; the first-matched route is used and all others are ignored.

The way to solve your problem is to put the `get '/baskets/owned'` route before the `resources` route.